# Access outer classes from imported module

Tags: python, python-import

I am moving a function from one file to another because it was getting too big, and I need access to all the variables and classes the function originally had access to in the first file. Should I get these to the function by passing them as arguments? Passing a class as an argument seems like a strange thing and I would appreciate any alternatives.

```py
class Thing:
    pass

def func():
    t = Thing()
    return t

func()
```

I am trying to move `func` to a different module that is imported by the above file, but I still need `Thing` to be defined in `func` after it has moved.

Comment: generally, you import a module you need in another module.

Comment: Having a class and its "instanciator" in different modules sounds weird too actually. Maybe you can define `func` as a classmethod of `Thing`?

Comment: this is purely an example, i didnt even realize that `func` was the instanciator of `Thing`. I just wanted to show that `Thing` needs to be defined for `func` to work.

Comment: "Getting too big" isn't really a reason to move a function from one module to another. If the function truly *is* getting too big, you should refactor it into smaller functions, some of which may not depend on the current module and can be safely moved.

Comment: In general, though, you have a design issue that we can't resolved based on the limited information shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to move the shared functions and classes to their own module and have that be imported by the module containing `Thing` and the module containing `func`.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing a specific object:

```
from my_module import Thing
```

Or if you want everything (*not recommended*):

```
form my_module import *
```

Comment: the problem with this is that the module containing `func` is imported by the module containing `Thing`, so if I import `Thing` from the other module, it'll be a circular import

Comment: `form my_module import *` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @lolcubes If that causes a circular import, you should probably rethink the design of your code, as others have commented.